# DB2: Can not delete rows from empty table after it was referenced in foreign key

Tags: db2, foreign-keys, constraints, sql-delete, ibm-midrange

There is an **empty** table called `ADDRESS`.

I perform `DELETE FROM ADDRESS` and everything is OK.

There is another **empty** called `ADDRESSMAPPING`.

Now I add a foreign key constraint to `ADDRESSMAPPING` which references `ADDRESS`.

```
ALTER TABLE ADDRESSMAPPING 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ADDRESSMAPPING_ADRESS_ID
FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS
```

When I then perform `DELETE FROM ADDRESS` the following error occurs:

> [55019][-7008] [SQL7008] ADDRESS in MY_SCHEMA not valid for the
>   operation

Both mentioned tables are still empty. If I remove the constraint the `DELETE` statement terminates again properly.

Why does this error occur? And how can I fix it?

Comment: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.hardware.ibm.midrange/217136

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0005250.html

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski It really seems to be that journaling isn't enabled.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski After adding journaling to the tables it's working.
Please convert your first comment to an answer so that I can tick it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Described problem occurs because the tables are not journaled. Adding journaling to the tables should solve the problem.